# Handling Spaces in fields of incoming POST request in Action argument

Tags: sap-cap

I have a requirement where I am getting a post request payload from a system to my CAP application where fields contains blank spaces. Now I wanted to create Identifiers for my actions arguments to take the incoming input. I wanted to know how we can put spaces while creating our Identifiers.

Entity Definition:

[image: Entity Definition]

Incoming payload :

`{ "data": [ { "Security ID": "6788361819397", "Work Order ID": "GE5AWO00000054", "Worker ID": "BE5AWK00000035", "First Name": "Luís", "Last Name": "Barreto", "Worker Email": "fg_qatest8@sap.com", "Start Date": "11/22/2023" } ]}`

When I am trying to pass the values without spaces I am getting this Deserialization Error :

[image]

Thank you

I read some documentations but did not got any positive results

Comment: Please [DO NOT post images](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.